# How to get the specific TEXT from website to excel?

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I Am trying to copy the text form the website in excel.

```
<input type="text" name="txtTimeStudyNbr" size="15" align="left" maxlength="10" value="4747526">
```

But the code is not working .So If someone helps me to fix this. I will feel awesome.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range(B2).Value = Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").innerText
```

```html
<td>
Time Study Nbr:<img src="../images/closeup.gif" height="11" width="11">
<input type="text" name="txtTimeStudyNbr" size="15" align="left" maxlength="10" value="4747526">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
Copy From Time Study: <input type="text" id="txtcopytimestudynbr" name="txtcopytimestudynbr" size="10" maxlength="10" value="">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;     
</td>
```

```
Sub copy_project_loop()

Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "URL"

Do While IE.Busy
     Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set Doc = IE.document

For intRow = 2 To 10

    Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range(B2).Value = Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").innerText
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would start by adding `id="txtTimeStudyNbr"` inside of your first input tag, considering you're using `doc.getElementById()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the name attribute by its value

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range(B2).Value = Doc.querySelector("[name=txtTimeStudyNbr]").value
```

Looks like you have a loop which will overwrite the current cell value by the way.

Comment: I tried but still not working_Set Doc = IE.document
    
For intRow = 2 To 11

    Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click
    
    Doc.getElementById("txtcopytimestudynbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("Copy").Click

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("B" & intRow).Value = Doc.querySelector("[name=txtTimeStudyNbr]").innerText

    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click
    
Next

Comment: What does not working mean? Is there an error message? Where does it occur?

Comment: No Error message . at the same time it is moving to next step.It is not bringing the inner text value to excel. so Please help me to fix this .                  Will that be possible to call the Value and get the text? because                                                            
<input type="text" name="txtTimeStudyNbr" size="15" align="left" maxlength="10" value="4747526">                                                                                                                                                  or copy paste method?

Comment: Are you sure you are not overwriting it? Put a stop inside the loop after the first time of writing to sheet. To get value attribute use Doc.querySelector("[name=txtTimeStudyNbr]").value

Comment: Thank you soooo muchh!!!!   this is working perfectly now                               Doc.querySelector("[name=txtTimeStudyNbr]").value

Comment: Qharr,  Can you help me for the below question . Please assist me on the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/61641828/13382552