# HOW to Click OK or CANCEL button to a “Pop message from Web-Page” using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

> How to Click OK or CANCEL button to a "Pop message from Web-Page". I am not able to take the elements of it. so if someone could help i will feel awesome.Images enclosed for your reference.I Have updated the web page frame details.

```html
        function button_onclick(button) {var thedate
     thedate = new Date(); 
     document.cookie = "hkClientrequest=" + thedate.getTime();
      
      switch (button.name) {
      case "Delete":
       if (isBlank(button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.value))
                  {alert("Please enter the Time Study Number!")
                    button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.focus()
                    return false} 
                  var TimeStudyNbr = 
        document.thisForm.txtTimeStudyNbr.value;
       if (TimeStudyNbr != "" && 
        isNaN(parseInt(document.thisForm.txtTimeStudyNbr.value, 10)))
       {alert("Please enter a number for Time Study Number!")
        document.thisForm.txtTimeStudyNbr.focus()
        return false }
       if (!confirm("The header information will be deleted!"))    
        return false  
       break; 
     
     
           case "Delete":

       thedate = new Date(); 
       document.cookie = "hkClientrequest=" + thedate.getTime();
       if (isBlank(button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.value)) 
       {alert("Please enter a \"Time Study Number\".")
        button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.value = 0
        button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.focus()
        return false}

       if (isNaN(button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.value) == true) 
       {alert("Please enter a \"Numeric Time Study Number\".")
        button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.value = 0
        button.form.txtTimeStudyNbr.focus()
        return false} 


       // JWH 11/28/01  2976 start
       // -------------------------------------------------------
       // Test if user has selected 1 or more Del checkboxes
       // -------------------------------------------------------
       iNumToDel = numChecked(button.form.chkDel)
       if (iNumToDel == 0)
       {
     
        alert(
         "In the Del column please Check 1 " +
         "or more qualifiers to delete."
        );

        return false
       }

       // Test if all checkboxes were selected.
       // Don't allow this.


       if ( isChkDelOK(button) == false )
       {
        alert(
        "Please leave at least one Qualifier undeleted\n" +
         "for each of these Qualifier types: MY.");

        return false}

      if (!confirm( iNumToDel + " qualifier(s) will be deleted!"))
       {return false}

    //alert( "jwh After Confirm." ); // jwh

   // Check if Qualifier that is selected using the radio button
   // is also being deleted.
   var bQualBeingDeleted = false;

   bQualBeingDeleted = isQualSelectedAndDel(currRow,button.form.chkDel);

    //alert( "jwh bQualBeingDeleted = " + bQualBeingDeleted ); // jwh

       // Test if qualifier is selected with the radio button and
       // also being deleted.
       if ( bQualBeingDeleted == true ) 
       {

  //alert( "jwh About to clear Qualifier Type and Valid Qualifiers"); 
 //jwh

 // Clear Qualifier Type, and Code select 
 // selectByValue(document.thisForm.lstQualifierTypes,null);
  SelectByValue(document.thisForm.lstQualifierTypes, "");
         
  lstQualifierTypes_onchange(document.thisForm.lstQualifierTypes)

  selectByValue(document.thisForm.lstQualifiers, "");
  // selectByValue(document.thisForm.lstQualifiers, null);

  //alert( "jwh Cleared"); // jwh
  // JWH 11/28/01  2976 end}
       else
  {
   // Select Qualifier Type in Select widget 
    var fieldName = "QualifierType"+currRow;
    var QualifierType = ""

   if (currRow != -1) {eval("QualifierType=document.thisForm."+fieldName+".value");}

 selectByValue(document.thisForm.lstQualifierTypes, QualifierType)
        lstQualifierTypes_onchange(document.thisForm.lstQualifierTypes)

 // Select Qualifier Code in Select widget 
   var QualifierCode = ""
 fieldName = "QualifierCode"+currRow;

 if (currRow != -1) {eval("QualifierCode=document.thisForm."+fieldName+".value");}

selectByValue(document.thisForm.lstQualifiers, QualifierCode)}
```

```
Sub copy_project_loop()

Dim IE As Object
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Dim SHELL_OBJECT
SHELL_OBJECT = "WScript.Shell"
Set objShell = CreateObject(SHELL_OBJECT)

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "URL"

Do While IE.Busy
     Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
Set Doc = IE.document

For intRow = 2 To 63

    Doc.getElementById("txtTimeStudyNbr").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("A" & intRow).Value
    Doc.getElementById("Search").Click

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Doc.getElementById("Delete").Click

    Do  While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Application.SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("B" & intRow).Value = "Deleted"
Next
End Sub
```

[image]

[image][image][image]
[image]

Comment: is there a public url? The first looks like can be removed by correctly entering info. The other two you will need to inspect the page for the relevant window.confirm's and see if either you can alter alert and directly perform whatever the associated actions are.

Comment: I have updated the page source and the elements form the page. So will you be help me on this.

Comment: Also please tell is there any option to press enter key.